# Problem with puppeteer, array.from not showing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, puppeteer

I have some issues with my code, my array.from works by themselves, but when combined into objects they do not show anything. Help please

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = 'https://example.com';
    await page.goto(url);

    const titles = await page.evaluate(
        () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.segmentation h3")).map((partner) =>
            partner.innerText)
            );

    const OrgNumber = await page.evaluate(
        () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.segmentation .org-number")).map((partner) =>
            partner.innerText)
            );


    let Bolag = await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.segmentation")).map((compact) => ({
            titles: compact.querySelectorAll("h3").innerText,
            OrgNumber: compact.querySelectorAll(".org-number").innerText
        }))

    );
        console.log(divs);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: can you explain more about `my array.from works by themselves, but when combined into objects they do not show anything`?

Comment: and also can you confirm `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.segmentation h3")).map((partner) =>
            partner.innerText)` this works in an actual browser?

Comment: Hi 
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.segmentation h3")).map((partner) => partner.innerText)... Works just fine,

what i mean by combined, is that I tried to make the first 2 arrays 
array.from (div.segmentation h3) + (div.segmentation .org-number) 
into an object, whereas object [h3, org-number] 

hope this clears it up a little.